# Find and remove a list item based on the item's third element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to find and return the first item in a list when that item's third element matches a value passed into the function. I then need that item to be permanently removed from the list.

I have written this function to do it and am wondering if there are any built-in functions that might accomplish the same without this fairly messy implementation:

```
(defun find-remove-third (x) 
  (let ((item (first (member x *test-list* :key #'third)))) 
    (setf *test-list*  (remove item *test-list* :test #'equal)) 
    item))
```

Operation:

```
CL-USER> *test-list*
((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 4 4) (5 4 3) (6 5 4) (2 2 2))
CL-USER> (find-remove-third 4)
(2 3 4)
CL-USER> *test-list*
((1 2 3) (3 4 5) (4 4 4) (5 4 3) (6 5 4) (2 2 2))
CL-USER> (find-remove-third 4)
(4 4 4)
CL-USER> *test-list*
((1 2 3) (3 4 5) (5 4 3) (6 5 4) (2 2 2))
```

For example `pop` mutates and returns from a list, though is more limited, but I'm wondering if anything more elegant than my function above might be possible, or if this implementation is normal and idiomatic?

Comment: why find and remove it? why not just remove it?

Comment: @RainerJoswig find it so I can use it (the other parts of it, that is (first and second elements when searching based on third)

Comment: you've re-implemented `prog1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation scans the list twice, so it is suboptimal.

I don't think you can write what you need without an explicit loop (or, equivalently, recursion):

```
(defun pop-from-list (object list &key (key #'identity) (test #'eql) kept)
  "Like `remove', but return the object removed as the second value."
  (let ((1st (car list)))
    (if (funcall test object 1st)
        (values (revappend kept (rest list))
                1st)
        (pop-from-list object (rest list) :key key :test test
                       :kept (cons 1st kept)))))
```

Now you can define your function like this:

```
(defun find-remove-third (x)
  (multiple-value-bind (list object)
      (pop-from-list x *test-list* :key #'third)
    (setq *test-list* list)
    object))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - Deleting this doesn't seem right so I'll leave it up, but as noted by @sds and @WillNess in the comments, this has serious issues.

Here's a destructive version which only scans the list once. It has the potential benefit that you don't have to hardcode the name of the list you're operating on.

```
CL-USER> (defun find&remove (list obj &key (key #'identity) (test #'eql))
           (loop with last = nil
                 for cons on list
                 when (funcall test obj (funcall key (first cons))) do
                    (progn (setf (rest last) (rest cons))
                           (return (first cons)))
                 do (setf last cons)))

CL-USER> (defvar test-list (list (list 1 2 3)
                                 (list 3 4 5)
                                 (list 5 6 7)
                                 (list 8 9 10)))

CL-USER> (find&remove test-list 5 :key #'third)
(3 4 5)
CL-USER> test-list
((1 2 3) (5 6 7) (8 9 10))
CL-USER> (find&remove test-list 7 :key #'third)
(5 6 7)
CL-USER> test-list
((1 2 3) (8 9 10))
```

The key is to traverse the list by cons cell rather than by item (`loop for ... on` rather than `loop for ... in`) and keep a  pointer to the  parts of the list we've already looked at (`last`). Then, when we find what we're looking for, we connect the `cdr` of what we'd already seen to the *next* cons (so now the list  omits the "hit") and finally return the result.

Comment: note that you cannot remove the last remaining list element destructively. moreover, your function will error out when called to operate on the first list element: `(find&remove test-list 1 :key #'third)`

Comment: @sds last should be easy, first is ... hard.

Comment: @WillNess: "the last remaining list element" is also the first; it _is_ possible to remove the first element by replacing it with the second one, but when there is no second element, you are stuck because you cannot turn a `cons` into a `nil`.

Comment: @sds yes that's what I meant by "hard"... didn't think what if it's the only one; you're right. :) so that's why you used `revappend` in your answer?... I see now.

Comment: Yikes, good point - and I know better. Obviously I didn't think this through enough.

Comment: +1 for not deleting this. visitors to this page can learn a lot not just from an optimal answer, but also from discussion around a suboptimal answer. thanks.